# ng-if does not validate function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does ng-if not validate the function I pass through it as either true or false? The div element is not displayed even if the condition is met.

**controller.js**

```
$scope.getCategoriseScore = function(profile) {
    var currentRating = this.profile.currentRating;
    if(currentRating >= 961 && currentRating <= 999) {
        var scoreRange = "excellent";
        return scoreRange;
    } else if(currentRating >= 881 && currentRating <= 960) {
        var scoreRange = "good";
        return scoreRange;
    } else if(currentRating >= 721 && currentRating <= 880) {
        var scoreRange = "fair";
        return scoreRange;
    } else if(currentRating >= 561 && currentRating <= 720) {
        var scoreRange = "poor";
        return scoreRange;
    } else if(currentRating >= 0 && currentRating <= 560) {
        var scoreRange = "very poor";
        return scoreRange;
    }
}
```

**view.html**

```
<div class="row" ng-if="getCategoriseScore() <= 961">
</div>
```

Comment: `getCategoriseScore()` returns the string. And you're comparing it with number in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your original question, you are returning a string instead of a number result to compare.

Also you defined a function that expects a parameter from where I think you want to get categorie scores. You should use it or remove the parameter.

```
<div class="row" ng-if="getCategoriseScore(PROFILE) <= 961">
```

Answer (score 0):

n00b mistake. This fixed it.

```
<div class="row" ng-if="profile.currentRating <= 961">
</div>
```